# How to get source code from .jar file

Tags: java, jar

I have my project in .jar file.

But i lost the source code of it.

How to get source code from .jar file.

Comment: I would try decompiling it.  I prefer fernflower which is built in to Intellij (can be run stand alone)  In particular it has better support for Java 8 IMHO.

Comment: Will be the Same code as i had written?

Comment: It is code which will do the same thing, if successfully decompiled. Not all information like comments is stored in the JAR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all I would like to tell you that if your project is big and complex, you are in trouble. Generated source code via external tools(no matter whatever the tool is) is never same as the real code. Code like comments, constants, inner classes, etc gets messy.

For simpler code and projects you can use -

- Java Decompiler (JD-GUI) http://jd.benow.ca/
- DJ Java Decompiler http://www.neshkov.com/dj.html

But always know this that its not what was written originally in the source code.

Comment: Other handy tools are - [Cavaj Java Decompiler](http://cavaj-java-decompiler.en.softonic.com/), [JBVD - Java Bytecode Viewer & Decompiler](https://sourceforge.net/projects/jbdec/), [AndroChef Java Decompiler](http://www.neshkov.com/ac_decompiler.html), etc.

Comment: Thanks for qidnes and Sorry for late response @Vikrant Verma

Answer (score 1):

You must decompile your code. You can use Java decompiler http://jd.benow.ca/